# Not enough free space error while compiling a model with Neuron SDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to compile a model on Sagemaker Studio with AWS Neuron SDK in order to run the model on inferentia instance. I'm getting the following error during compilation phase.

```
ERROR:Neuron:Not enough free space to write 268435456 bytes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_neuron/convert.py", line 413, in op_converter
    neuron_function = self.subgraph_compiler(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_neuron/decorators.py", line 135, in trace
    weight_paths = write_params(model_dir, constant_parameter_tensors, constant_param_key_mapping)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_neuron/decorators.py", line 1517, in write_params
    np.save(f'{directory}/weights/{file_name}.npy', weight.numpy())
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in save
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 529, in save
    format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 691, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: Not enough free space to write 268435456 bytes
```

Command

```
# Compile the model using the wrapper
compiler_args = ['--verbose','1', '--num-neuroncores', str(1)]
optimizations = ['FLOAT32_TO_FLOAT16']
model_neuron = torch.neuron.trace(mpt_model, example, compiler_args=compiler_args, optimizations=optimizations, separate_weights=True, strict=False)
```

Model - `mosaicml/mpt-7b-instruct`

AWS Sagemaker instance - `ml.m5.4xlarge`

Running `df -h` on the terminal shows that the overlay filesystem is being used to write the files during compilation.

[image]

The two possible resolutions I can see is to

- Either increase disk space
- Or use another directory to write temporary files during neuron compilation

But I don't see a way to pass custom storage path in neuron SDK API and neither a way to extend the filesystem storage

Neuron API Ref - https://awsdocs-neuron.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/frameworks/torch/torch-neuron/api-compilation-python-api.html#torch_neuron.Optimization